# iContact API: can't get "updateContact" PHP function to work

Tags: php, api

I need to use iContact's API to update the street address in a single contact record.

The API is here: https://github.com/icontact/icontact-api-php

Specifically, I want to update `street2`.

In the API, there's an "updateContact" function which takes 15 parameters. Here's an example:

`updateContact($currentContactId, null, null, null, null, null, null,'My second address', null, null, null, null, null, null, null);`

The API builds the URI so that's OK. It also sets it to POST (also ok; that's what's needed by the API to update the contact).

Here's an example of the URI built by the API:

https://app.sandbox.icontact.com/icp/a/913463/c/133578/contacts/67295434

The last digits `67295434` is the unique ID for the contact.

The BODY request also looks ok:

`[{"street2":"My second address"}]`

BUT the JSON response after the `curl_exec` I get is this:

```
  {"contact":
    {
    "contactId":"67295434",
    "prefix":"Mr.",
    "firstName":"Joe",
    "lastName":"Williams",
    "suffix":"Jr.",
    "street":"2365 Meridian Parkway",
    "street2":"",
    "city":"Durham",
    "state":"NC",
    "postalCode":"27713",
    "phone":"8668039462",
    "fax":"",
    "business":"iContact",
    "email":"joewilliams@icontact.com",
    "createDate":"2013-03-30 21:22:28",
    "bounceCount":"","status":"normal",
    "interestedinseo":"1",
    "wheredoyoulive":"New York"
    },

    "warnings":["Invalid field: 0"]
  }
```

I suspect a bug in the API but can't spot it. Or am I missing something stupid? Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [iContact API](http://developer.icontact.com/documentation/contacts/) is expecting the update JSON string in this format:

```
{"street2":"My second address"}
```

However, the API wrapper is sending the update data in this format:

```
[{"street2":"My second address"}]
```

So you'll need to change this line in function updateContact():

```
$oContact = $this->makeCall("/a/{$this->setAccountId()}/c/{$this->setClientFolderId()}/contacts/{$iContactId}", 'POST', array($aContact), 'contact');
```

...to this:

```
$oContact = $this->makeCall("/a/{$this->setAccountId()}/c/{$this->setClientFolderId()}/contacts/{$iContactId}", 'POST', $aContact, 'contact');
```

Comment: Worked like a dream - Thanks Steven!